# Is there a rvm env variable for configure flags?

Tags: ruby, rvm, rvmrc

instead of:

```
rvm install 2.6.6 -C --with-jemalloc
```

Can I somehow set an environment variable so that I can install rubies without passing configure flags?  That is:

```
rvm install 2.6.6
```

It seems there's this `$rvm_configure_flags` var [all throughout the rvm codebase](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/search?q=rvm_configure_flags) so I tried setting that in my environment:

```
$ echo $rvm_configure_flags
--with-jemalloc
```

However that appears to not be used, or its clobbered somehow.  I've `echo $rvm_configure_flags` all throughout rvm codebase and can't seem to find where it's getting clobbered.

A fairly old(?) example .rvmrc file appears to suggest this is possible:

https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/examples/rvmrc#L90-L92

Answer (score 1):

The command `rvm help install` shows the following:

```
#### .rvmrc equivalents

- `--with-arch`                       `rvm_architectures`
- `-C`                                `rvm_configure_flags`
        ... or per-ruby:              `{jruby|ree|rbx|mruby|macruby|truffleruby}_configure_flags`
- `-E`                                `rvm_configure_env`
- `-M`                                `rvm_make_flags`
- [none]                              `rvm_curl_flags`; default: --max-redirs 10 --max-time 1800
```

This implies that `-C` is equivalent to `rvm_configure_flags`. The documentation has this additional example:

````
A variable with multiple flags should be set using parentheses and space 
separators. E.g. .rvmrc for `brew`-based `readline`, `llvm`, and 
`openssl` libraries:
```
 # warning: don't use \ linebreaks or it will break.
rvm_configure_env=( LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix llvm)/lib -L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(brew --prefix llvm)/include -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" CXX=$(brew --prefix llvm)/bin/clang++ CC=$(brew --prefix llvm)/bin/clang )
rvm_archflags="-arch x86_64"
```
````

I've also confirmed that setting `rvm_configure_flags` in `~/.rvmrc` has the intended effect of passing those options to the `./configure` step.

Answer (score -1):

The [RVM documentation](https://rvm.io/rubies/installing) has a section on compile flags:

> If you need to pass compile flags for the compile process, just set the corresponding environment variables.
>
> As an example, to enable gdb for ruby 2.1.1:
>
> ```sh
> $ export optflags="-O0 -ggdb"
> $ rvm install 2.1.1
> ```

Comment: opt flags is too generic - looking for a rvm specific env var

Comment: @jsharpe The RVM-specific way to do it is listed in the [documentation](https://rvm.io/rubies/installing). [Don't rely on private interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9386355/3784008) and you won't get bitten by encapsulation issues.

Comment: thanks for the update - just because 'optflags' is in the documentation doesn't make it rvm *specific*.  yes, it makes it *supported*, but not *specific*.  optflags doesn't work for the given problem.